# Visual Studio Build error after copy solution to new location

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I inherited Visual Studio 2010 Web Site solution.
The solution is pretty simple (but large), and only contains one project.

BUT when I copy the site to another location on my hard drive and try to build it, I get the following error:

Error    1   
**An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to** 'C:\Development\SolutionFolder\app_code' **because access is denied.**  C:\Development\SolutionFolder\app_code\web.config

Comment: Have any access restriction on the target location? The exception is 'access is denied'.

Comment: You might have copied it to another user's document folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some impersonation issue. Please check the local user permission on the app_code folder.

Comment: Many thanks 'Tariqulazam' your are correct, after switching off impersonation solution build. Agh don’t the simplest thing trip you up ;0)